# Java create seperate classes for initialization and methods

Tags: java, optimization

I'm starting java after C#, so want some advice:

when you create a form in C# it creates several files :

Designer -  where all items are initialized

and "main" - where user writes code for example actionlistener for buttons.

In Java all of these are put in the same file.

So question is, is it possible to devide it?
Is it appropriate way, or I should put everything into one class(I talking about items of forms and event listeners)?

It would be nice if you suggest something better for more easy-reading code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can do whatever you want 8)

The main difference between java and C# in that respect is probably that C# and its toolset strongly recommend one way of working. This is very different in Java. Since you are talking about forms I'll assume we are talking about swing here. But similar stuff applies for other toolkits.

One approach would be to have a class GUIFactory (with one central method) accepting a model (class Model) as an argument, and then creating, and initializing all the GUI elements, wiring them to the model, using Listeners. The model in that case would fire events, which trigger Listeners, which would update the UI.

This should be simple enough for getting started when you have C# experience yet get you the separation of concerns you seem to be looking for.

I wrote about [Clean Code Swing and Scala](http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2011/06/26/clean-code-with-swing-and-scala/), although it is Scala the same approach holds for Java as well, so it might be interesting for you.